# Get span title in jquery

Tags: jquery-ui

I want to retrieve span title in the following html.

```
<div id="header_customerid_d">
<div>
<span title="This is my span"></span>
</div>
</div>
```

I have tried with following jquery bt i got "undefined" alert.

```
var CustomerId = $('#header_customerid_d',this).children("div").children("span").attr("title");
alert(CustomerId);
```

So please provide me with correct solution.

Thanks,
Bharat Mhatre

Comment: It's not possible to help without seeing actual HTML. But you could try to debug with alert($('#header_customerid_d',this).children("div").html()); to see if right element is selected.

Comment: We need to have more javascript to help you (*this* can refer to anything in your code). You can also use debugging extensions like firebug and try some syntax

Answer (score 7):

`var CustomerId = $("#header_customerid_d span").prop("title");` should do the trick. See an example fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/f5tnS/).

Note that the `prop` function is only available in jQuery 1.6+. If you are using an older version of jQuery, use `attr` instead:

```
$("#header_customerid_d span").attr("title");
```

Comment: I am getting undefined alert here

Comment: Have you tried the fiddle I posted a link to? That does not alert `undefined`. If you're getting `undefined` in your code, then there's something else wrong. What version of jQuery are you using? `prop` is only available in 1.6. If you are using an older version, change `prop` to `attr`.

Comment: I'm using Jquery 1.6, may be I think this has got to do with the HTML generated by Micrsoft Dynamics CRM 2011, where I want to get the element located on the Parent form's div(the one above), and extract its span elements title to set my input value.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are not used to working with `id`, you can always assume the "order".

```
$('span')[0]
```

This bit of code gives you the first `span` element that you are interested in. But if I modify your code a tiny bit:

```
<div id="header_customerid_d">
<div>
<span id="sp_1" title="This is my span"></span>
</div>
</div>
```

Look at the `id` in the span that makes an easier jQuery:

```
$('#sp_1')[0].title
```

will return the title of the span that you are interested in. There are lots of jQuery tutorial on the web, but almost all of them recommends that you put an `id` for each of your HTML elements. It's your friend.

So, the code becomes:

`var CustomerId = $('#sp_1')[0].title;
alert(CustomerId);`

Of course, you might come back and say "Ey I don't have control over assignment of `id' attributes to all of my HTML documents, please give me something else!". In that case,

```
$('#header_customerid_d').children("div").children("span")[0].title
```

Should give you the `title` attribute. You can also use it is getter and setter i.e.

```
$('#header_customerid_d').children("div").children("span")[0].title = "blablabla"
```

will set the title to "blablabla".

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```
$('div#header_customerid_d').find("span").attr("title");
```

[See Here](http://jsfiddle.net/rWHuW/)

*And if there are multiple spans in div then you have to use [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to get each.*

Comment: I am getting undefined alert here

Answer (score 0):

You don't need, or want to include `this` in your jQuery selector call.

Change your code to this:

```
var CustomerId = $('#header_customerid_d').children("div").children("span").attr("title");
alert(CustomerId);
```

and it will work.

Or, if you want to be more concise, do as one of these other fine gentlefolk have suggested!

ian.